# How to turn a win xp into a ntp multicast server?

Tags: windows, ntp

Is there any tool (or maybe registry configuration, whatever) that turns a Windows XP machine into a multicast ntp server? I am looking for a freeware solution preferable.

Comment: Install Linux on it?  Why would you want a Windows XP box as a NTP server?

Comment: @Zoredache: that is for my work. We have four "operating units" here with one win xp machine each. There is a GPS clock available, but it has to be forwarded by the xp machine since it can not be reached by all members of the network. Unfortunately there is nothing I can change (operating system, protocol, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Meinberg port of NTPd](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm) is version 4.2.4p8 which is supposed to support Manycast. I have not actually used it (the Windows port for manycast) so I can not attest it it's functionality. I know the 4.2.4p5 version I use on *nix does support it.

An additional bonus to this route, it uses the exact same configuration file as the *nix version (same software, you'd expect as much). Also the `ntpq` and `ntpdc` utilities are included for diagnostics and testing.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope this helps you.

It is however not free but a small cost: http://www.han-soft.com/nettime.php

I do not know of any free versions that do multicast.